# Specific maximum function

Tags: haskell

Here is my code:

```
data Polindrom = Polindrom { a :: Integer,
                             b :: Integer,
                             c :: Integer } deriving (Show)


euler_4 = [ p | y <- [10..20],
                z <- [10..20],
                let x = y * z,
                let p = Polindrom { a = y, b = z, c = x },   
                let s = show x,            
                s == reverse s]
```

Now I need to find the element of euler_4 which have max 'c'.  In Ruby I have used such construction:

```
}.sort { |a, b|
  b[2] <=> a[2]
}[0]
```

How can I get it in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
maximumBy (\x y -> compare (c x) (c y))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import Data.Function

maximumBy (compare `on` c)
```

Answer (score 1):

A third possibility is `Data.Ord.comparing`:

```
maximumBy (comparing c)
```